# How to choose rows from a table, such that it adds up to a given vector?

Tags: summation

I have a table of food stuffs and their cost and dietary nutrient supply like say vitamins, calories, minerals etc.

I want to choose certain food stuffs from the table so that their summation meets at least the daily dietary requirements for the vitamins, minerals etc. I also want to minimize calorie and cost.

I can always try brute forcing, but is there a more efficient way to do it? I have also thought about using backtracking and genetic algorithms but they have a preposterous time complexity.

Heuristics are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had asked this question I had not taken a course on Linear Algebra. Now that I do, let me answer my own question.

The problem can be thought as $$x_1*v_1 + x_2*v_2 + ... + x_n * v_n = v$$ 
Where $v_i$ is the vector containing the nutrients of individual food stuffs. $x_i$ is the amount of this food stuff should be used for cooking.

Now we form a matrix $[v_1 v_2 ... v_n]$ and find any `m` linearly independent columns randomly where `m` is the dimension of $v_i$. We take these columns and form a new matrix, let us call it `A`. Since `A` is the basis of our original matrix we can say $$Ax = v$$ Solving for `x` will give an answer which satisfies the nutrient requirements.

As far as cost and calorie is considered, we can either fix it by including it in the vectors $v_i$, or we can find the minimal subset sum.